# Why information gain with entropy as impurity function can't be used as a splitting method for Decision Tree Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-trees, metric

In Decision Tree Regression, we can use 'Reduction in Variance' or MSE (Mean Squared Errors) as splitting methods. There are methods like Gini Index, Information Gain, Chi-Square for splitting on classification trees. Now, I read somewhere that we cannot use Information gain (with impurity function as entropy) as a splitting method for regression trees. Why is it so, and what other methods are there which we can and cannot use, and why?

**EDITS:**

Please suggest me a reference to understand maths behind it.

The references I used are :

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/04/complete-tutorial-tree-based-modeling-scratch-in-python/

https://www.python-course.eu/Regression_Trees.php

https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-lorrli-classification-and-regression-analysis-with-decision-trees-c43cdbc58054

In the first article, it is mentioned that:

> Gini Index, Chi-Square and Information gain (impurity function as entropy) algorithms are used for Classification trees while Reduction in Variance is used for Regression Trees.

In the second article, it is mentioned that:

> Since our target feature is continuously scaled, the IGs of the categorically scaled descriptive features are no longer appropriate splitting criteria.
>
> As stated above, the task during growing a Regression Tree is in principle the same as during the creation of Classification Trees. Though, since the IG turned out to be no longer an appropriate splitting criteria (neither is the Gini Index) due to the continuous character of the target feature we must have a new splitting criteria.
>   Therefore we use the variance which we will introduce now.

In the third article, it is mentioned that:

> "Entropy as a measure of impurity is a useful criterion for classification. To use a decision tree for regression, however, we need an impurity metric that is suitable for continuous variables, so we define the impurity measure using the weighted mean squared error (MSE) of the children nodes instead"

Thank You!

Comment: Entropy, information gain etc has the formula for calculating the probability for the particular class so can use for the classification and we build tree according to that but in the case of the regression, we can't go each value as a label as they are infinite. There may be another points also. Have a look at a tree https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-decision-tree-regression-using-sklearn/